# Connection Refused HTTPS 443 localhost

Tags: windows, apache-2.4, windows-server-2012-r2, openssl

I am running Windows Server 2012 R2 with Apache 2.4.  I'm having trouble with enabling HTTPS for some reason.  I've done this before and previously all that I did was

> 1.) Enable SSL inside Apache by un-commenting `LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so` from the httpd.conf.
>
> 2.) Add the entry into my virtual hosts file.
>
> 3.) Restart Apache and browse to the site over https

For whatever reason, it's not working.  When I browse over http all works as expected.  However, over https it does not connect.  So I performed the following tests.

> C:> telnet dev.mydomain.com 80 - connects fine telnet
>
> C:> telnet dev.mydomain.com 443 - Could not open connection to host on port 443. Connection failed.

So thinking it's a Firewall issue, I added a rule to allow port 443.  I even tried turning off the Firewall completely.  Neither worked.  Still get the connection failed error.

Can someone please point me in the right direction here?

Thank you!

Comment: Check for a missing Listen 443 or Listen ip:443 directive. Listen is the directive that actually tells apache to bind to a port.

Comment: @ezra - where would this be? in the httpd.conf file?  The reason I ask is I have SSL working on my other server, same apache version etc and the httpd.conf files are identical.  Neither one has Listen 443.

Comment: well, if you have servers listening in 443 port without the Listen directive, then I can safely say "it's magic". Now seriously, do review your configurations better.

Comment: @ezra-s - is there somewhere other than the httpd.conf file where this would be set?  I'm trying to fine where it is set on the server that is working and I can't seem to find it.

Comment: files mean nothing to httpd, what matters is context. "Listen" directive goes in "server config" context. So follow your "Include" directives for other files if it is not defined in the main configuration file.

Comment: @ezra-s - I just re-checked the server that IS working over HTTPS and I only have Listen 80 in the httpd.conf file.  Is there somewhere else this would be set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69583/discussion-between-ezra-s-and-phil).

Comment: @ezra-s - any include files to check WOULD be listed in the httpd.conf file though correct?  If i go through and check all include files there?  that's what you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After MUCH assistance from ezra-s I added

> Listen 443

to the httpd.conf file and HTTPS started working.  YAY!!!